# Making simple mathematical application giving error on loop

Tags: c#, arrays, math, for-loop, int

Im trying to make an auto solve for this math:

__ + __ + __ = 30, Fill the spaces using (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15), you can also repeat the numbers.

I made this code:

```
    int[] nums = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; j < nums.Length; k++)
                {
                    if ((nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k]) == 30)
                    {
                        result.Text += nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But i get this error when click the button to calculate: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in app.exe**

P.S.: Please do not spoil the answer for me.

Comment: _"Please do not spoil the answer for me"_ -- what does that mean? Do you want an answer or not? The exception message is pretty clear. What about it are you having trouble understanding? Did you use the debugger to inspect the code statement where the exception occurs, and to see what index was in fact out of range?

Comment: He means not the answer to the arithmetic puzzle.

Comment: What is `nums1` in the inner most loop?

Comment: Also not to spoil it, but three odd numbers cannot add up to an even number.

Comment: 11 items in the array isn't divisible by 3.

Comment: Why not learn how to use the debugger?

Comment: I mean do not spoil the math solution, anyway i never used the debugger i'm little noob here but trying my best to learn, here's a screenshot of the full error: http://i.imgur.com/f5J7pZs.png

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @mike z sorry it's it's a typo.

Comment: And the `j` in the inner most loop condition, should be a `k`.

Comment: _"i never used the debugger"_ -- Sounds like a great time to start. :)

Comment: Don't know to use the debugger but i'll start to learn, thank you guys, mike got it point it was a dump mistake, i just copied the second loop into to the third without changing the __k__, also this math is just stupid it's waste of time i got no solution for it because there's none, but at least i learned something here. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code

```
for (int k = 0; j < nums.Length; k++)
```

to

```
for (int k = 0; k < nums.Length; k++)
```

Comment: I didnt have enough reputation to comment. Else I would I have given it in your comments.

Comment: It could be nice if you can mark this as an answer. I am also a newbie to this.

Answer (score 0):

> int[] nums = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 };

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.Length; j++)
        {
           /* check conditional statement value of k exceeds length of the num element array*/
            for (int k = 0; j< nums1.Length; k++)
            {
```

/* could have been >> for(int k=0; k < nums.Length; k++)  */

```
                if ((nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k]) == 30)
                {
                    result.Text += nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] + "\r\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

:)